# Can someone explain the parameters tracked by "Personalized Prediction Data"?

Tags: discussion, support, privacy, personal-data

I downloaded my [personalized data](https://stackoverflow.com/users/prediction-data) and I saw some parameters I don't understand.

Can someone explain them?

- `DisplayAdPersonas`
- `Seniorities`
- `PredictionType`
- `TagPercents`

I think these are the most confusing ones, as the other ones are easier to understand from the name convention, but I don't think it will hurt if a complete answer is given (explaining each parameter tracked).

Comment: Related (but not answered): https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250062/documentation-on-the-personalized-prediction-data

Comment: In my Download from 2015, these (except for `PredictionType`) had not been included. But beyond these parameters, the *structure* of the data has changed considerably. I could imagine that the devs do not want to "document" it (which may cause others to *rely* on the data in any way...).

Answer (score 4):

This is what those parameters show for me:

```
"DisplayAdPersonas": {
 "BigData": 0.0185441107163209,
 "Cloud": 0.0460837117725306,
 "DevOps": 0.0281699718062293,
 "FrontEnd": 0.33013315812635,
 "IOT": 0.0134595417557633
},
"Seniorities": ["MidLevel"],
"PredictionType": "PersonalizedPredictions",
"TagPercents": null
```

The names seem pretty self-explanatory, especially with the context of their values:

- `DisplayAdPersonas`: Areas of interest to display ads for, with a weight.
- `Seniorities`: This seems to be an estimate of your seniority (Junior > Medior > Senior) as a employee in your field of interest.
- `PredictionType`: What type of prediction should be used, probably changes to something other than `"PersonalizedPredictions"` if you turn off personalized predictions.
- `TagPercents`: For this one I have no clue.

Comment: *seems to be*, *probably changes to*, *no clue* - my point exactly

Comment: Hey, it's still better than no answer at all ;-)
The _"probably"_ is more because I don't want to turn it off to test the result.

Comment: Thanks @Cerbrus. I'm still waiting for an official reply here. I'm curious how do they decide that your area of interest is IOT for example, or when do they decide you're a `MidLevel` senior, etc.